# error: requestFeature() must be called before adding content - Still won't work

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I know that similar questions have been asked in the past but I can't seem to get this working at all even with the suggestions.

I get the above abend on the "show()" command.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    try{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.submitscoredummylayout);                
    scoreloopInit();
AlertDialog whatToUploadDialog;
whatToUploadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YanivSubmitScoreActivity.this).create();
whatToUploadDialog.setContentView(R.layout.submitscoreprompt);
whatToUploadDialog.setTitle(R.string.uploadedScoreTitle);
whatToUploadDialog.setCancelable(false);


  ((CheckBox)whatToUploadDialog.findViewById(R.id.ckbScoreloop)).setChecked(settings.getUploadToSL());
  ((CheckBox)whatToUploadDialog.findViewById(R.id.ckbFacebook)).setChecked(settings.getUploadToFB());

  ((CheckBox) whatToUploadDialog.findViewById(R.id.ckbScoreloop)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() { 

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton ckBox, boolean isChecked) {
                settings.setUploadToSL(isChecked,true);
                findViewById(R.id.btnYes).setEnabled(isChecked||settings.getUploadToFB());
            }
            }); 

  ((CheckBox) whatToUploadDialog.findViewById(R.id.ckbFacebook)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() { 

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton ckBox, boolean isChecked) {
                settings.setUploadToFB(isChecked,true);
                findViewById(R.id.btnYes).setEnabled(isChecked||settings.getUploadToSL());
            }
         });        

  whatToUploadDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnYes).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
                submitScore(SUBMIT_UPLOAD_TO_SL);
                whatToUploadDialog.dismiss();
      }
  });

  whatToUploadDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNo).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
                whatToUploadDialog.dismiss();
              finish();
          }
      });
whatToUploadDialog.show();
}
```

Logcat:

```
W/System.err(14969): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
W/System.err(14969):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:184)
W/System.err(14969):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:198)
W/System.err(14969):    at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:251)
W/System.err(14969):    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:307)
W/System.err(14969):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:225)
W/System.err(14969):    at ui.YanivSubmitScoreActivity.onCreate(YanivSubmitScoreActivity.java:105)
W/System.err(14969):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
W/System.err(14969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
W/System.err(14969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
W/System.err(14969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
W/System.err(14969):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
W/System.err(14969):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err(14969):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/System.err(14969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
W/System.err(14969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(14969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
W/System.err(14969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
W/System.err(14969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
W/System.err(14969):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please add your logcat error and full code snippet

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I experienced the same problem. I found that the problem only occurs if I do both of the following things:

- I don't use activity managed dialogs (`activity.showDialog()` ->
  `activity.onCreateDialog()`/`onPrepareDialog()`)
- I do `dialog.findViewById()` (and this is indeed the line difference
  between success or the requestFeature exception!).

```
final Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
b.setView(rootView);
b.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
b.setTitle(R.string.message_of_the_day_title);
b.setCancelable(false);
dialog = b.createDialog();
dialog.findViewById(R.id.myid); // this is the problem
```

The `dialog.findViewById()` causes the problem because it calls

```
dialog.getWindow().getDecorView()
```

and the method javadoc of  `getDecorView()` says:

> Note that calling this function for the first time "locks in" various
>   window characteristics as described in {@link #setContentView(View,
>   android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)}.

Isn't that nice, `findViewById()` has a side effect which causes seemingly correct applications to crash. Why there's a difference between `Activity` managed dialogs and normal dialogs I do not know, but I guess `getDecorView()` does some magic for `Activity` managed dialogs.

I did the above because I moved from using `Activity` managed dialogs to handling dialogs myself.

The solution for me is to manipulate the rootView, using `rootView.findViewById()`, instead of manipulating the dialog.

Comment: exactly! I think this is the main reason why this happens! After looking inside hundrets of questions regarding this problem with nonsense solutions, It will finally work! Want to add one thing: if one calls `dialog.show()` BEFORE `dialog.findViewById` everything works just fine. I think it has something to do with a DecorView not beeing inflated before the first call to `dialog.show()`

Comment: @rafael Window.findViewById at least has a [warning](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#findViewById%28int%29) about these side effects, but not Dialog.findViewById. I sent a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199710).

Answer (score 4):

Substitude the following line:

```
whatToUploadDialog.setContentView(R.layout.submitscoreprompt);
```

with:

```
whatToUploadDialog.setView(R.layout.submitscoreprompt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
.setTitle(R.string.uploadedScoreTitle);
```

before

```
.setContentView(R.layout.submitscoreprompt);
```