# Change AlertDialog title separator colour code giving exception

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I need to change the default blue colour of the separator line below the title of the AlertDialog just as asked in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under/15285514#15285514)

On Searching I found some work arounds to do so but on trying this code its giving exception.

**Heres my code:**

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Hello World")
            .setTitle("Alert Dialog")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Close",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
            );
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    try {
        ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) dialog.getWindow().getDecorView()).getChildAt(0))
                .getChildAt(1)
                .setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_orange));
    }catch (NullPointerException ex){
        Timber.e(ex.getStackTrace().toString());
    }
    dialog.show();
```

**And here is the LogCat:**

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.example/com.android.example.activities.HomeScreenActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:318)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:235)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:337)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:363)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:264)
        at com.android.example.fragments.HomeScreenFragment.onActivityCreated(HomeScreenFragment.java:114)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:958)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1189)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5436)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for the exception you get?

Comment: yup! The problem is where to place the code try{}catch(). And i did not find any post for the complete code

Comment: possible duplicate of [requestFeature() must be called before adding content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250149/requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content) please read the first message of your exception to the end, also you generally **don't** catch runtime exceptions, you deal with them.

Comment: @CeilingGecko: I am aware of the statement  **requestFeature() must be called before adding content ** but there is no setContentView in my code i am using a AlertDialog().Builder and dont know where to post my try_catch code. If you have any link which handle's this issue in case of a dialog then this question can be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @username_AB check this answer to know why your app crashes http://stackoverflow.com/a/15572855/1276636

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `getDecorView()` creates the decor view if it doesn't exist.

Calling `show()` on a dialog calls `requestFeature()` and it will fail with this exception if the decor view has already been created. Most often the decor view is created by the first call to `setContentView()`. Hence the wording in the exception.

The code seems hacky, but you can try moving the try-catch involving `getDecorView()` after the dialog `show()`.